# How do I pass value from a input to another input and automatically load base on the input?

Tags: php, jquery

On first.php
I use jquery location.href ="www.localhost.com/second.php?text="+param to pass the input parameter to second.php (on hitting enter).
code for first.php:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#txt").keypress(function() {
            var name = $("#txt").val();
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            location.href = "http://www.localhost.com/second.php?text="+param;
            }
        });
    });
```

On second.php
I get the value using $("#").val(decodeURIComponent($.urlParam("text")));
However I cannot get it to load automatically after the second page loads. So I am force to let the input value and data load when the input field is click. 
here is the jquery:

```
$("#txt").one("mouseup", function() {
    $("#txt").val(decodeURIComponent($.urlParam("text")));
        var variable = $("#txt").val();
        $.post("xxxx.php", {
            text: variable
            }, function(data, status) {
            $("#show").html(data);
            return;
        });
});
```

Comment: `$("#")` ? Don't you have an ID to go with that? Can you post some HTML? Also `location.href =` is not jQuery and will load a new page

Comment: Yes, I have an id.I make the update. As I mention it is working. Just cannot figure how to get it load automatically(without the mouse click.

Comment: This code is total nonsense to me. Why not to use $_GET table server-side and render what you want on second.php without ajax call?

Comment: Kwas. I am trying something new so you would have to explain what you mean by $_GET table server-side. On the first.php I get a text input. when you type and hit enter. I pass the parameter through the URL of the second page input. However, I cannot get the script to trigger unless I use the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out the answer to the question. To load the data immediately on second page(second.php) the Jquery script I added was:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#txt").val(decodeURIComponent($.urlParam("text")));
            var variable = $("#txt").val();
            $.post("xxxx.php", {
                 text: variable
                  }, function(data, status) {
                    $("#show").html(data);
                 return;
             });
    });
});
```

There wasn't any need to add a listener for the window to load. The listener is already in the library.